# Disable "Collection [local.oplog.rs] not found." log entry on MongoDB 7.0 arbitrator

Tags: mongodb, logging, configuration

I have installed MongoDB Community Edition (ver. 7.0.4) in architecure of PRIMARY-SECONDARY-ARBITER. The thing is that on arbiter logs I see many warnings likr this:

```json
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-16T11:23:07.001+01:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"QUERY",    "id":23799,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Aggregate command executor error","attr":{"error":{"code":26,"codeName":"NamespaceNotFound","errmsg":"Unable to retrieve storageStats in $collStats stage :: caused by :: Collection [local.oplog.rs] not found."},"stats":{},"cmd":{"aggregate":"oplog.rs","cursor":{},"pipeline":[{"$collStats":{"storageStats":{"waitForLock":false,"numericOnly":true}}}],"$db":"local"}}}
```

In my opinion, this information makes no sense on the arbitrator node, because there is no local.oplog.rs collection on arbiter (like any other collections).
I don't think that I saw something like this on older versions of MongoDB. The question is - How to disable only these warnings without changing all other log messages?

I tried to change logging verbosity, but that doesn't work the way I wanted. I want to only ride off this one message from logs of an arbiter node.

Comment: I get the same and [others too](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/arbiter-logging-error-every-second/250346). Seems to be a bug, I created a ticket for it: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-85279